# My jquery code is not running in the proper order and I can't tell if a file exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code to check if a file exists and if it does, do one thing and if it doesn't, do another by creating a variable.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").keyup(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
        
                var exists = false;
                var filename = "folder/document.html";

                $.get(filename, function() { //This code only runs if a certain file exists
                    exists = true;
                    alert('should be displayed first');
                });

                if(exists == true) {
                    alert('This file exists!');
                } else {
                    alert('This file does not exist!');
                } 
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="myInput" role="textbox" contenteditable></span>
</body>
```

The problem with it is that for some reason, $.get runs after everything else, no matter what I do. Why is this happening and how do I solve it. I'm fine with a totally new method of checking if a file exists, but this is the best I could find. The $.get releases a 404 error if it does not find a file, meaning that the code inside of it only runs if it finds a file, which is why I had it set a variable inside of there and had the if statement be reliant on the variable.

PS: the code only works if it is uploaded to the internet, not as a file on a computer, which is really annoying.

Comment: `.get()` is asynchronous. It's an AJAX function. Move your `if(exists == true)` block inside your get

Comment: move the alerts into the `get()` callback.

Comment: "the code only works if it is uploaded to the internet, not as a file on a computer, which is really annoying" It would be even more annoying if any website you browsed could access your local filesystem....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Just to clear up, I can't move the alert or the if statement into the get() because the code inside of it only runs when it finds a file, meaning that if I do that, how do I run the code that I need when it doesn't find a file without running it when I do? I can't use continue because the get() runs after the rest of everything.

Comment: That's not what's happening.  The `get()` is running first, but it's asynchronous, so the response doesn't come back until later; meanwhile the rest of your keydown function runs.  Code that needs to wait for the response from the `get` needs to be in a callback function -- you probably want both `.done()` and a `.fail()` callbacks, for when the file does and does not exist.

Comment: Is there a way to make the get() synchronous, I don't mind the wait because I'm planning on loading the file if it is found anyway.

Comment: [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re), but it's deprecated, was a terrible idea and should never be used (it blocks _all_ activity until the call returns.). If you're going to do web coding you need to get familiar with asynch code,  it's just the nature of the beast

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I just figured it out and it works now. Thank you so much. Here is the code I'm using now from another question which didn't work when I tried it earlier, but it is all good now:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").keyup(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
                var exists = false;
                var filename = "folder/document.html";
                $.get(filename)
                .done(function() {
                alert('File exists!');
                }).fail(function() { 
                  alert('File does not exist')
                });         
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="myInput" role="textbox" contenteditable></span>
</body>
```